# Why can't I make cross origin requests to an API hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET WebApi application running locally using IISExpress that allows me to accept requests from any domain. I am doing this using a `DelegatingHandler` similar to the one provided one [this blob post](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/Using-CORS-With-ASP-NET-Web-API/).

Locally this runs perfectly however after uploading to an Azure Website, I get the typical `'Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'` under Chrome.

I've tried to debug this by adding trace statements into the Handler with no output and it seems like SendAsync is never being executed, almost as if IIS is responding to the OPTIONS request instead of passing it on to my application.

Has anyone come across anything similar going from development to production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS (including the one in your Azure web site) has a default OPTIONS handler. You will need to remove it in Web.config. It answers the OPTIONS call before your message handler has an opportunity to respond.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      ...
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And it would appear that IISExpress does not.

Comment: Yes, that's why you did not face this issue until you deployed in IIS. Same behavior can be seen in local IIS server as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem on Azure Websites running PHP. IIS still responds before the request is actually passed to the PHP code.